# How object allocated in the heap measuring time？

Tags: object, garbage-collection, object-lifetime

When I read the book 《The Garbage Collection HandBook》， the chapter 9
impile that:"object lifetimes are better measured by the number of bytes of heap space allocated between their birth and death.". I am not very understand this sentence. why lifetime can be measured by the allocated bytes? I try to google for that, but I get no answer.
Who can explain that to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By measuring object lifetimes in terms of bytes allocated between instantiation and death, it is easier for the GC algorithm to adapt to program behaviour.

If the rate of object allocation is very slow, a simple time measurement would show long pauses between collections, which would appear to be good.  However, if the byte allocation measurement of object lifetimes is high objects may be getting promoted to a survivor space or the old generation too quickly.  By measuring the byte allocation the collector could optimise heap sizes more efficiently by expanding the young generation to increase the number of objects that become garbage before a minor collection occurs.  Just using time as this measure would not make the need for the heap resizing obvious.

As the book points out, with multi-threaded applications it is hard to measure byte allocation for individual threads so collectors tend to measure lifetimes in terms of how many collections an object survives.  This is a simpler number to monitor and requires less space to record.

Answer (score 2):

“time” is only a scale that allows to bring an order to events. There are many possible units, even in the real world. Inside the computer, for the purpose of garbage collection, there is no real world’s time unit needed, all the garbage collector usually wants to know, is, which object is older than the other.

For this purpose, just assigning an ascending number to each allocated object would be sufficient, but this would imply maintaining an additional counter. In contrast, the number of allocated bytes comes for free. It’s important that we accumulate the allocated bytes only, never subtracting deallocated bytes, so we have an always growing number.

In a generational memory management, this number doesn’t need to be updated on every allocation, as objects are allocated continuously in a dedicated space, so their addresses represent their relative age within this memory region whereas the start of the region is associated with the last garbage collection. Only when the garbage collector runs and moves the surviving objects, it has to merge this information into an absolute age, if needed.

Implementations like the HotSpot JVM simplify this further. For surviving objects, it maintains a small counter holding the number of garbage collection cycles it survived. After having survived a configurable number of collection cycles, it gets promoted to the old generation and beyond that point, the object’s age becomes irrelevant.

Comment: you say:" In contrast, the number of allocated bytes comes for free". Then,How to count allocated bytes for every Object between their birth and death?  Do every object need an additional counter,or some other way? I am a little puzzle.

Comment: As long as the youngest objects live in the same space, the last object’s end equals the number of allocated bytes. As said, the relative age must be merged with the base age of that memory space (the time of the last gc) in the next garbage collection cycle *if* tracking the absolute age through different memory spaces is intended. This may imply needing storage to hold that information But normally, JVMs do not track that age to the object’s death; JVMs won’t even detect an object’s death at all. They only care about the survivors.